# Apache POI doesn't find highlighted text

Tags: java, apache-poi, highlight, doc

I have a file saved in doc format, and I need to extract highlighted text.
I have code like in following:

```
HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
        Range r = document.getRange();
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            CharacterRun t = r.getCharacterRun(i);
            System.out.println(t.isHighlighted());
            System.out.println(t.getHighlightedColor());
            System.out.println(r.getCharacterRun(i).SPRM_HIGHLIGHT);
            System.out.println(r.getCharacterRun(i));
        }
```

None of the above methods show that text is highlighted, but when I open it, it is highlighted.
What can be the reason, and how to find if the text is highlighted or not?

Comment: Is really the character run highlighted as described in https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-or-remove-highlighting-1747d808-6db7-4d49-86ac-1f0c3cc87e2e? Or is there applied shading on a word or paragraph as described in https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-shading-to-words-or-paragraphs-2020d0e0-f99e-4d53-a895-009077cbcfda?

Comment: I do not really how was it highlighted, but for example if I want to detect both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting text in `Word` is possible using two different methods. First is [applying highlighting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-or-remove-highlighting-1747d808-6db7-4d49-86ac-1f0c3cc87e2e) to text runs. Second is [applying shading to words or paragraphs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-shading-to-words-or-paragraphs-2020d0e0-f99e-4d53-a895-009077cbcfda).

For the first and using `*.doc`, the `Word` binary file format, `apache poi` provides methods in [CharacterRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html). For the second `apache poi` provides [Paragraph.getShading](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Paragraph.html#getShading--). But this is only set if the shading applies to the whole paragraph. If the shading is applied only to single runs, then `apache poi` provides nothing for that. So using the underlying  `SprmOperation`s is needed.

[Microsoft's documentation 2.6.1 Character Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd947480(v=office.12).aspx) describes `sprmCShd80 (0x4866)` which is "A Shd80 structure that specifies the background shading for the text.". So we need searching for that.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.sprm.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class HWPFInspectBgColor {

 private static void showCharacterRunInternals(CharacterRun run) throws Exception {
  Field _chpx = CharacterRun.class.getDeclaredField("_chpx"); 
  _chpx.setAccessible(true);
  SprmBuffer sprmBuffer = (SprmBuffer) _chpx.get(run);
  for (SprmIterator sprmIterator = sprmBuffer.iterator(); sprmIterator.hasNext(); ) {
   SprmOperation sprmOperation = sprmIterator.next();
System.out.println(sprmOperation);
  }
 }

 static SprmOperation getCharacterRunShading(CharacterRun run) throws Exception {
  SprmOperation shd80Operation = null;
  Field _chpx = CharacterRun.class.getDeclaredField("_chpx"); 
  _chpx.setAccessible(true);
  Field _value = SprmOperation.class.getDeclaredField("_value"); 
  _value.setAccessible(true);
  SprmBuffer sprmBuffer = (SprmBuffer) _chpx.get(run);
  for (SprmIterator sprmIterator = sprmBuffer.iterator(); sprmIterator.hasNext(); ) {
   SprmOperation sprmOperation = sprmIterator.next();
   short sprmValue = (short)_value.get(sprmOperation);
   if (sprmValue == (short)0x4866) { // we have a Shd80 structure, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd947480(v=office.12).aspx
    shd80Operation = sprmOperation;
   }
  }
  return shd80Operation;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("sample.doc"));
  Range range = document.getRange();
  for (int p = 0; p < range.numParagraphs(); p++) {
   Paragraph paragraph = range.getParagraph(p);
System.out.println(paragraph);
   if (!paragraph.getShading().isEmpty()) {
System.out.println("Paragraph's shading: " + paragraph.getShading());
   }

   for (int r = 0; r < paragraph.numCharacterRuns(); r++) {
    CharacterRun run = paragraph.getCharacterRun(r);
System.out.println(run);
    if (run.isHighlighted()) {
System.out.println("Run's highlighted color: " + run.getHighlightedColor());
    }
    if (getCharacterRunShading(run) != null) {
System.out.println("Run's Shd80 structure: " + getCharacterRunShading(run));
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```